# Is there a way to log into a keycloak protected web site from the command line?

Tags: authentication, command-line-interface, keycloak

I am interested to log into a SSO protected web site. I am presently using mellon (`mod_auth_mellon`) but am willing to change that to any other SSO protection.

I need the web site to throw up a username/password login page that is authenticated by SSO on the back end and I need to be able to log into this website from commandline (e.g. curl).

I know that for an https website that requires username/password login, I can do `https://username:password@URL` -- this does not work with SSO.

I have googled. It seems that I need a redirect (which I am unfamiliar with).

Has anyone done this already ?